# From element to element script

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to pass from a function to another function? (script>script) <= element
how do I pass the value of the field validator into the second function?

```
<script>
             $('#card_number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
            if (result.valid) {
                const infosuccess = result.card_type == null ? '-' : result.card_type.name
                const valid = result.valid
                const validlunn = result.luhn_valid
                const validlenght = result.length_valid 
                console.log(infosuccess);
            } else {
               //  $(this)
               //  const inforeject = result.valid

               //  console.log(result);
               
            }
         }); 
         </script>
```

```
      <script>
        $('#nextaction').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
              // my code...
  })
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you not just read the value from the field in the `click` handler? i.e. `$('#card_number').val()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I don't understand how to do it, sorry.

Comment: I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass arguments directly in to event handlers. However, there are other approaches you can use.

In this case you can set the 'Next' button to be disabled when the page loads. You can then enable/disable it depending on the result of the credit card validation.

To retrieve the entered card number you can simply read the value from the input when the button is clicked, like this:

```js
const $cardInput = $('#card_number');
const $validateBtn = $('#validate_card');
const $nextBtn = $('#next-action');

$cardInput.validateCreditCard(function(result) {
  $nextBtn.prop('disabled', !result.valid); // enable/disable 'next' button

  if (result.valid) {
    // update the UI to show card details if necessary here...
  } else {
    console.log('enter a valid credit card number...');
  }
});

$nextBtn.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const cardNumber = $cardInput.val();
  
  console.log(cardNumber);
  console.log('move to next action here...');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-creditcardvalidator/1.0.0/jquery.creditCardValidator.min.js" integrity="sha512-7omJBgl5QF4QuC3Ge745IO3rDZVMrZWIGK8lSs5lQIFxbWt4d2c7YQg3ZcnonFyRuQslrJ1Ai33Zj/rnXC15+Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<p>
  Test Card number: 5404000000000084
</p>

<label>
  Credit card number:
  <input type="text" id="card_number" />
  <button type="button" id="validate_card">Validate</button>
</label>

<button type="button" id="next-action" disabled>Next...</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Work.
only how do I pass the value true to my function?
try: `const valid = '' valid.push(result.valid) $nextBtn.on('click', function(e, valid) {` Only it doesn't work for me xD

Comment: For what reason do you need that value? The only way you would ever get to the next page is if `result.valid` was `true` in order to make the 'Next' button be clickable. So if the user has reached that page, then you know the card is valid.

Comment: That being said, just a note - if this is for a production system then you shouldn't be doing card validation in this manner at all. Do it server side.

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks for reminding me.
I just want to output only (result.card_type.name) and put it in its function

Comment: That can be done in the first code block, where I added the 'update the UI here...' note.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I asked how to get it PUSH? Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: although PUSH also cannot be routed to another block